# Having trouble with centering tables

Tags: html, css, html-table, alignment, center

I'm having a problem with getting these tables to align in the center. I have tried to align it to center and I tried to margin it to auto. I can`t find out how to fix it. Can someone help me?

HTML CODE:

```
<div style="background-color:#BA1919;">
    <table class="tab_nav" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-left:1px solid #951414">SCHOOL</td>
                <td>AIA CAMPUS OFFLINE</td>
                <td>HELP DESK</td>
                <td>THEATRE</td>
                <td>CLOUD</td>
                <td>ISV BUILDING</td>
                <td>LOCAL PUB</td>
                <td>LIBRARY</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS CODE:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px){

body {
padding:0px;
background-image:url(Gray.png);
background-repeat:repeat;
}

.site {
display:none;
}

.tab_nav td {
padding:15px 5px;
border-right:2px solid #951414;
}

.tab_nav {
margin:auto;
font-weight: bold;
color: #FFFFFF;
text-decoration: none;
text-align:center;
font-size: 12px;
display: block;
}

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The table is centred, the problem is that it is also the width it needs to take up all the horizontal space in its container.

By default a table will be `display: table` and will shrink wrap its contents (i.e. be only as wide as it needs to be) but you have overridden that with `display: block`.

Remove `display: block` from the rules for `.tab_nav`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a wrapper class name inside your div.

```
<div class="wrapper" style="background-color:#BA1919;">
    <table class="tab_nav" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td style="border-left:1px solid #951414">SCHOOL</td>
                <td>AIA CAMPUS OFFLINE</td>
                <td>HELP DESK</td>
                <td>THEATRE</td>
                <td>CLOUD</td>
                <td>ISV BUILDING</td>
                <td>LOCAL PUB</td>
                <td>LIBRARY</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

in your CSS add this

```
.wrapper{
 width: 500px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: You could play around with the width, you could also set the width to 600px. http://fiddle.jshell.net/vf3C5/ check this

Answer (score 0):

They do not center because the table itself takes up 100% of the div's width. To center the table, give it a width which is smaller than the outer div.

Comment: I need like 90% of the div size.